# What embedded OS is suitable for fujitsu FM3 family microcontroller? (ARM Cortex M3)

Tags: operating-system, embedded, cortex-m

Currently i am studying ARM Cortex M3 micon from fujitsu.
What OS that has been ported to this micon?
I prefer proprietary OS.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Wait, you prefer a *proprietary* OS?

Comment: Yes i prefer using proprietary OS.. Do you have any idea

Comment: No, I have no idea. I was just making sure you didn't leave out non- before proprietary.

Answer (score 3):

I would look at uCOS-II and FreeRTOS, both of which readily support Cortex M3.

Comment: Thanks.Do you know what development tools available for above OS?

Comment: Careful @Debby Nirwan, FreeRTOS it not proprietary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at [rt-thread](http://www.rt-thread.org/), [coocox](http://www.coocox.com/), [ecos](http://ecos.sourceware.org/).
All of these RTOSes support Cortex-M3.